# NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials in Hugging Face Library

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, huggingface

So i am not using Huggin face a lot for my ai but I've discover that you can train you're ai with it so it tried to use my machine to train it but i kept having that error:

```
PS C:\Users\gboss\OneDrive\Bureau\Ai training> & C:/Users/gboss/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/gboss/OneDrive/Bureau/Ai training/AiTraining.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gboss\OneDrive\Bureau\Ai training\AiTraining.py", line 8, in <module>
    role = iam_client.get_role(RoleName='{IAM_ROLE_WITH_SAGEMAKER_PERMISSIONS}')['Role']['Arn']
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 514, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 921, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 944, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 119, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 198, in _send_request
    request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 134, in create_request
    self._event_emitter.emit(
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\signers.py", line 105, in handler
    return self.sign(operation_name, request)
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\signers.py", line 189, in sign
    auth.add_auth(request)
  File "C:\Users\gboss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\auth.py", line 418, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError()
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

and let's say that i can't find why because i don't use huggin face a lot

the code:

```
import sagemaker
import boto3
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFace

# gets role for executing training job

iam_client = boto3.client('iam')
role = iam_client.get_role(RoleName='{IAM_ROLE_WITH_SAGEMAKER_PERMISSIONS}')['Role']['Arn']
hyperparameters = {
    'model_name_or_path':'ZipperXYZ/DialoGPT-medium-TheWorldMachineExpressive2',
    'output_dir':'/opt/ml/model'
    # add your remaining hyperparameters
    # more info here https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/v4.17.0/examples/pytorch/language-modeling
}

# git configuration to download our fine-tuning script
git_config = {'repo': 'https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git','branch': 'v4.17.0'}

# creates Hugging Face estimator
huggingface_estimator = HuggingFace(
    entry_point='run_clm.py',
    source_dir='./examples/pytorch/language-modeling',
    instance_type='ml.p3.2xlarge',
    instance_count=1,
    role=role,
    git_config=git_config,
    transformers_version='4.17.0',
    pytorch_version='1.10.2',
    py_version='py38',
    hyperparameters = hyperparameters
)

# starting the train job
huggingface_estimator.fit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to configure your credentials, its not an error in your code. Follow this [thread](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/using-sagemaker-in-jupyter-notebook/9970)

TLDR:

```
NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Reply: Yes let me explain this, it is a bit complicated to get started. So the `IAM ROLE`, which you have created will be used inside the SageMaker Training Job/Inference. Meaning this ROLE is used to, e.g. download your data from s3 or is needed to start the underlying machine.

The error `NoCredentialsError`: Unable to locate credentials is shown when you don’t have credentials configured on your machine. You need to run aws configure so set up IAM Credentials (User) on your machine. You need these credentials to start your training job.

Comment: So uh do i need to have an aws complete account for that even if i train it on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Need to configure access key
touch ~/.aws/credentials
vim ~/.aws/credentials

# Add the following configuration
[default]
region=ap-southeast-2
aws_access_key_id=***************
aws_secret_access_key=******************

# How to get access_key and secret_access_key see the link below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html
```